# Csv file creation like unicodetext, endig .csv. VBA unable to o open, save and close with changes

Tags: excel, vba

This is my first question here. I always find answer on google. But now I am lost.
I have been trying, to create a CSV file. Everything was ok but then I found some Cyrillic letters in my export. This problem I solved with following code:

```vb
Set shtToExport = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Text")  'Sheet to export as CSV
Set wbkExport = Application.Workbooks.Add
shtToExport.Copy Before:=wbkExport.Worksheets(wbkExport.Worksheets.Count)
Application.DisplayAlerts = False                  'Possibly overwrite without asking
wbkExport.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\" & Environ("username") & "\Desktop\AP Import.csv", FileFormat:=xlUnicodeText
```

Save file as Unicode text. This solved my problem with Cyrillic letters and question marks were gone.
I was happy until I try to upload this file. Nothing happened.
Then I opened the CSV file, and after closing Excel asked me to save, so I did it and then MSG box "*Some features in your workbook might be lost if you save it as Unicode"* I pressed yes and tried to upload file again. And it worked perfectly.
But I am not able to put close and save with above mentioned msgbox in code. I tried:

```vb
workbooks(AP Import.csv).save 
Workbooks(AP Import.csv).close SaveChanges = True
```

What I want, is open AP import.csv, save, press yes to msgbox "...... you save it as Unicode Text" But I am not able do it with macro. I succeeded to get "Want to save your changes to..." But not unicode msg box. I am using Excel 2013

Here is whole code:

```vb
Sub Test()
    '
    ' Test Macro

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    If IsEmpty(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("data").Range("A1")) Then
        MsgBox ("Vlož data z WebGate exportu")
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim wbkExport As Workbook
    Dim shtToExport As Worksheet

    Columns("S:W").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Temp").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

    Range("F1").Select
    Sheets("data").Select
    Columns("E:E").Select
    Selection.Replace What:=" ", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
    Range("E:E,I:I").Select
    Range("I1").Activate
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Temp").Select
    Range("F1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("H1").Select
    Sheets("data").Select
    Columns("L:O").Select

    Range("L:O,X:X,Z:Z").Select
    Range("Z1").Activate
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Temp").Select
    Range("H1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("A2").Select

    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=357
    Range("A2:G800").Select

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("To update").Select
    Range("A2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("H2").Select
    Sheets("Temp").Select
    Range("N2").Select

    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=354
    Range("N2:Q800").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("To update").Select
    Range("H2").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("A1").Select

    Set shtToExport = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Text")  'Sheet to export as CSV
    Set wbkExport = Application.Workbooks.Add
    shtToExport.Copy Before:=wbkExport.Worksheets(wbkExport.Worksheets.Count)
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False                  'Possibly overwrite without asking
    wbkExport.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\" & Environ("username") & "\Desktop\AP Import.csv", FileFormat:=xlUnicodeText ' " & Date & "

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    ThisWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add after the save:

```
wbkExport.Close
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. But i need that file to save with aking me "Some features in your workbook might be lost if you save it as Unicode" Its ease to close open save. I need to to same, when you click on quicksave button. Than excel ask me that question about unicode. Then is csv file ready to upload.

Comment: I don't think the message is key here. Have you checked both saved files and compared the VBA-saved one with the manually saved one? They may be different because VBA speaks "American".

Comment: When VBA saves my csv file, what is basically txt file with .csv suffix, update completed but values not changing. Then when i open my file, press save button, unicode msg box appear. I press yes, then update file and values are changed.